# extracting a fill method from a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a combobox on a windows form that I fill with a list of names.  At the moment I have the following code inside the Form class and it works fine

```
    // This section opens a connection to the database, selects all the portfolio names that have an "in Use" value of 1, and then
    // fills Combo Box 2 with the values. 
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = ""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf""; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand2.Connection = myConnection;
        myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT Portfolio_Name FROM Dbo.Name WHERE In_use = 1";
        SqlDataReader myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();
        while (myReader2.Read())
        {
            comboBox2.Items.Add(myReader2[0]);
        }
        myConnection.Close();
```

I would like to be able to extract this into a separate method, and put it into a separate class for general utility methods.  However, I'm stuck on a really simple issue.  When I put the code into a class, I need to be able to tell it which combox box I want to fill, and I can't figure out how to pass in that information.  Sorry if the answer is obvious, but any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks!

Comment: When you do not know what combo box should be used, use the ComboBox value as a parameter in function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is so simple:

```
public class MyUtility
{
    public static void FillComboBox(System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox comboBox)
    {
        //comboBox.Items.Clear(); //enable this line if required
        using (SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = ""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf""; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30"))
        {
            myConnection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand())
            {
                myCommand2.Connection = myConnection;
                myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT Portfolio_Name FROM Dbo.Name WHERE In_use = 1";
                using (SqlDataReader myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (myReader2.Read())
                    {
                        comboBox.Items.Add(myReader2[0]);
                    }
                }
            }
            //myConnection.Close(); //not required inside using block
        }
    }
}
```

you may use other methods to get connection string (e.g. from config file).

The usage is so simple, no extra code required:

```
MyUtility.FillComboBox(comboBox2);
```

Comment: `myConnection.Close();` is *redundant* - the connection will be closed on `using (SqlConnection myConnection = ...) {...}` scope

Comment: @Dmitry Bychenko yes i just left it from original code which is copy-pasted from the question. thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to extract, then extract:

```
// Let's extract a class: it should provide us standard cursors, 
// e.g. Protfolio Names 
public static class MyData {
  // Let's enumerate items returned
  public static IEnumerable<string> PortfolioNames() {
    // Wrap IDisposable into using
    //TODO: move Connection String into a separated method/property 
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(/*connection string here*/)) {
      con.Open();

      // Make sql readable 
      //DONE: when presenting something to user, sort it (order by) esp. strings
      string sql = 
        @"  select Portfolio_Name
              from Dbo.Name
             where In_use = 1
          order by Portfolio_Name"; 

      // Wrap IDisposable into using
      using (SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand(sql, con)) {
        // Wrap IDisposable into using 
        using (var reader = q.ExecuteReader()) {
          while (reader.Read())
            yield return Convert.ToString(reader[0]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then  use

```
// Adding items in one after one manner is often a bad idea:
// it makes UI repaint each time you add an item and cause blinking.
// Let's fill the ComboBox in one go via AddRange  
comboBox2.Items.AddRange(MyData.PortfolioNames().ToArray());
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a helper class names `Portfolio` for data access. The method `GetNames` does not require a `ComboBox` instance. This increases the chance that you can reuse the method in another context.

```
public static class Portfolio
{
    public static IList<string> GetNames()
    {
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB; AttachDbFilename = ""C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Investments 4.mdf""; Integrated Security = True; Connect Timeout = 30");
        myConnection.Open();
        SqlCommand myCommand2 = new SqlCommand();
        myCommand2.Connection = myConnection;
        myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT Portfolio_Name FROM Dbo.Name WHERE In_use = 1";
        SqlDataReader myReader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();
        var portfolioNames = new List<string>();
        while (myReader2.Read())
        {
            portfolioNames.Add(myReader2[0]);
        }
        myConnection.Close();
        return portfolioNames;
    }
 }
```

Then in your Form you can do something like this:

```
var names = Portfolio.GetNames();
foreach (var name in names)
{
    combobox2.Items.Add(name);
}
```

Comment: Ah yes, this is my next stage!  Thanks rboe